# PHP, run code without opening windows on the webbrowser

Tags: php, background

If I have a list of elements, and via javascript the user moves the elements in another order, can I, after each move, launch a php code (like a php page) but without having to call it in the browser?

Comment: you can to it with ajax..

Comment: you could use jquery if you are unfamiliar with ajax and want a quicker result. specifically check out [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Are there serious difference between the two?

Comment: I'll be checking jQuery.ajax, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create an XmlHttpObject for the URL, send() it, check results to see if the call was successful, and discard the responseText. As an example, suppose you have the new order in a variable testUrl, e.g., "http://domain.com/script.php?order=1,4,3,2"

```
var xmlHttpObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttpObject.open("GET", testUrl, false);
xmlHttpObject.send();
var xmlText = xmlHttpObject.responseText;

if (xmlText == 'Success')
    // do nothing
else
    alert (xmlText);
```

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the above answer - for the sake of posterity, in case someone has to debug your code some day :) I use the following function call to get that object: (I believe it makes the JS more readable and portable). You can check the return value and if null, alert the user that AJAX is not supported by the browser.

```
function getXmlHttpObject () {
    var xmlHttpObject = null;
    try {
        xmlHttpObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (ex) {
        try {
            xmlHttpObject = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        } catch (ex) {
            xmlHttpObject = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }
    }
    return xmlHttpObject;
}
```